# Why is this Symfony annotation not working?

Tags: symfony, routes

Before I start, I should mention that this is **Symfony 2.8.25**. (I just started working on this code base, and once we get some critical issues resolved, we'll be upgrading.)

I have an *existing* class using **annotations** with a number of routes that work fine.

I added a new one, and I get a 404 on that one every time.  I did a `console cache:clear` which did not help.  When I did a `console debug:route`, the new Routes *appear in the list*.  But I still get a 404 on them, while the others in the same source file work.

All the routes use a POST, the working and non-working ones.

The routing.yml looks like this:

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation

logout:
    path: /logout
```

The class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\Environment;
use AppBundle\Entity\Instance;
use AppBundle\Entity\Migration;
use AppBundle\Entity\UserActivity;
use AppBundle\Entity\Task;
use AppBundle\Form\Environment\EnvironmentType;
use AppBundle\Services\Api;
use AppBundle\Utils\HashRequest;

class EnvironmentController extends Controller
{
...
    /**
     *
     * @Route("/api/envtype/add", name="api_envtype_add")
     *
     */
    public function addEnvtypeAction(Request $request){
...
```

When I try another route from this same class, it works.  But not this new one.

I tried renaming the route, and that made no difference.  I checked the annotation comment for TABs, since that's a (semi-)known bug in older versions.  No TABs in the annotation.

This annotation looks to me exactly like the others that work.  (None of them have a `@return`, for example.)

PostMan reports `No route found for "POST /api/envtype/add"`

I am completely out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

in `namespace`:

`use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;`